# Usage of non-SDK interfaces, Google play console

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-pie

actualmente estoy desarrollando mi primer app, por lo que no soy un experto en android, el punto es que he subido mi app para hacer pruebas a la consola de google play, pero en el apartado "Reporte previo al lanzamiento" (donde se prueba el apk en diferentes niveles de api de android) me dice que tengo un problema para android 9 con un icono rojo y con el mensaje de:

> Problema: Usage of non-SDK interfaces

He leído [esto](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces), [esto](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/improving-stability-by-reducing-usage.html) y algunas otras entradas más, y por lo que entiendo es que buscan evitar que los desarrolladores utilicemos elementos de android y java que no han sido diseñados para ser utilizados directamente.

En el emulador, mi app funciona como debe en ese nivel de api pero en logcat genera entradas tales como (solo cito algunas, realmente son muchas):

```
Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ActivityThread;->currentActivityThread()Landroid/app/ActivityThread; (light greylist, reflection)
Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/ActivityThread;->mActivities:Landroid/util/ArrayMap; (light greylist, reflection)
```

Incluso en un proyecto recién generado también me genera entradas de ese tipo, y por lo que veo todas las entradas que me genera pertenecen a light greylist.

¿Es ese realmente un impedimento para que yo lance mi app en la playstore?

de serlo, ¿Qué debeo hacer para identificar donde se está accediendo a dichos métodos y/o atributos?

Para agregar, quiero aclarar que no tengo acceso a un dispositivo fisico con dicho nivel de api.

Agradezco su atención.

Answer (score 2):

El mensaje :

> Usage of non-SDK interfaces

Se refiere a que estas haciendo uso de Clases, métodos, atributos que no son parte del SDK pero que son accedidos en tiempo de ejecución. Recuerda que podemos acceder a estos elementos mediante [reflexión (Reflection)](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/learn-java-for-android-development-reflection-basics--mobile-3203).

En este caso mencionas que estas usando [Android 9](https://www.android.com/versions/pie-9-0/) y precisamente en esta versión del sistema operativo se esta [**empezando a prohibir el acceso vía reflection a estos elementos**](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/improving-stability-by-reducing-usage.html).

Por ejemplo, en el `LogCat` puedo ver que tienes este mensaje:

> Accessing hidden method
>   Landroid/app/ActivityThread;->currentActivityThread()Landroid/app/ActivityThread;
>   (light greylist, reflection)

Probablemente en tu código tienes:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

Method m = activityThread.getMethod("currentActivityThread", new Class[0]);
```

Revisa el documento: [Mejora de la estabilidad al reducir el uso de interfaces que no son SDK (inglés)](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/improving-stability-by-reducing-usage.html)

---

> ¿Es ese realmente un impedimento para que yo lance mi app en la
>   playstore?

Te sugiero que mientras revisas tu código y lo modificas, definas en tu archivo `build.gradle` como máximo:  `compileSdkVersion 27`  y `targetSdkVersion 27` y generes de esta forma tu .APK.

> ¿Qué debeo hacer para identificar donde se está accediendo a dichos
>   métodos y/o atributos?

en tus clases estarías haciendo uso de los `import`:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
```

también de `Class.forName()`, ejemplo :

```
 Class<?> cls = Class.forName("Jorgesys");
```

Comment: Lo de bajar el sdk parece ser lo mas conveniente (aunque me molesta... ), me gustaría saber que piensas de que incluso un proyecto limpio y recién generado me da entradas de ese tipo en logcat.